# Using JQuery in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm writing my own Drupal 7 module, and like to use JQuery in it.

```
$('#field').toggle();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

It seems that JQuery is not loaded. Otherwise $ should be defined.

Though I actually include it in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rockfinder.de/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
```

Do I have to do anything else to activate JQuery in Drupal? Is $ being overwritten by Drupal?

That's the website: http://rockfinder.orgapage.de

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[From the Drupal 7 upgrade guide:](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility)

> Javascript should be made compatible
>   with other libraries than jQuery by
>   adding a small wrapper around your
>   existing code:
>
> ```
> (function ($) {
>   // Original JavaScript code.
> })(jQuery);
> ```
>
> The $ global will no longer refer to
>   the jquery object. However, with this
>   construction, the local variable $
>   will refer to jquery, allowing your
>   code to access jQuery through $
>   anyway, while the code will not
>   conflict with other libraries that use
>   the $ global.

You can also just use the 'jQuery' variable instead of the $ variable in your code.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this syntax in Javascript.  Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: It basically creates an alias from $ to jQuery. As said above, the reason for this is to include other JS libraries which are using the $.

Comment: For some reason that gave me a long error message, but when i just replaced $ with jQuery it worked just fine.

Comment: @Jim The code is wrapped into a function having a parameter $. Then it is called with jQuery, which executes the function by replacing all instances of $ with jQuery. This is one of the three methods to work around the '$ is not a function' issue (see http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/05/about-jquery-usage-in-drupal.html)

Answer (score 14):

According to Firebug, your jQuery file is being loaded:

[image]

But the `$` is being overwritten by something else:

[image]

---

What you should do is encapsulate the use of the `$` variable with a function that invokes itself using the `jQuery` object as it's first actual argument:

```
(function ($) {

 // in this function, you can use the $ which refers to the jQuery object

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: So.. why is $ not defined? Is it being overwritten?

Comment: It's to avoid conflicts with other Javascript libraries such as Prototype.

Answer (score 8):

Chances are your script is not initialized this way, you'll have to use Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

/*Add your js code here*/
alert('Code');

}

};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: shouldn't you use `}(jQuery));` instead of `})(jQuery);` on the last line of your code?

Comment: you absolute legend, this is it! Everyone listen, this is how you do it in Drupal!!!!

Answer (score 1):

"$ is not a function" is a very common error that you may face while working with jQuery. You can try any answers of given below:

```
(function($){
//your can write your code here with $ prefix
})(jQuery);
```

OR

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//Write your code here
});
```

Basically this will allow our code to run and use the $ shortcut for JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the separate file for js and than add js file using the following:

```
drupal_add_js('path', 'module_name');
```