# Jquery script not loading in Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal

I am having trouble getting a Jqery script to work on my first drupal 7 site. I have everything working locally outside of drupal so I know the script works. I included the script in the .info file and it shows up on the page in firebug. For some reason the script won't read. I do have document.ready included, jquery is installed on the site. What else could be the problem? Is there something about drupal and how it handles script file I don't know about?

Thanks for the help all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery in Drupal 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681309/using-jquery-in-drupal-7)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: try to use

```
jQuery("something")...
```

instead of

```
$("something")...
```

I have fixed my problem with this.

Comment: try to use the firebug console something with jQuery: does it work?
Without any code it's hard to help you.

Comment: Well I did swap out the $ with jquery. What are you suggesting I do? The script runs on page load so any changes in FB wouldn't update anyway... i don't think.

Comment: My bad you all were right. I didn't capitalize the Q in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // javascript here
  });
})(jQuery);
```