# Use jquery to show / hide menu in Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, menu

I have a ctools content type plugin with a template file with the following html in it:

```
<a id="blah">Click me</a>
<p class="green-button"><a href="#">Read the blog</a></p>
<ul class="buying-dropdown">

      <li class="first amazon"><a href="#">paperback</a></li>
      <li class="signed"><a href="#">Signed edition</a></li>
      <li class="kindle"><a href="#">kindle edition</a></li>
      <li class="hardback"><a href="#">hardback edition</a></li>
      <li class="last postcard"><a href="#">postcard edition</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to simply show the ul on mouseover of the p button, maintain state for the duration of hovering over and selection of the different child li and then disappear on mouseout.

The javascript file is being called, as if I look in console then console is writing 'called'. However, my simple 'click me' button test isn't working. I have also tried to achieve the main goal (following this tutorial http://www.queness.com/preview/1047/easy-to-style-jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial) with the menu, but it seems that my script isn't being called. Any help appreciated.

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    console.log('called');
    $('#blah').click(function() { console.log('clickity click')});
    //when someone mouseovers the buy book button
    //the menu will show (it is hidden by default  
    //the menu will stay open whilst hovering over   
    //on mouseout the menu disappears
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Comment: what does the console tells you? i would try this http://jsfiddle.net/K6ZrT/

Comment: The console says 'called', but not 'clickity click' as expected when I click #blah

Comment: I tried your fiddle, but the same is happening e.g. no 'clickity click' as expected when I click #blah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution. Answered originally on [Using JQuery in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681309/using-jquery-in-drupal-7)

```
  (function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

     console.log('called');
        $('#blah').click(function() { console.log('clickity click')});
        //when someone mouseovers the buy book button
        //the menu will show (it is hidden by default  
        //the menu will stay open whilst hovering over   
        //on mouseout the menu disappears
    }

    };
    })(jQuery);
```